# How can I split a mixed string in c#

Tags: c#

Here is sample input and output.
I have  strings  like as following.
I want to increment string last digit by 1

AVAP001P001 output AVAP001P002

CD009 output CD010

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, what isn't working and expected output.

Comment: It is possible only if you have a pattern with which you can parse part of the string, convert into int, increase and replace it with an old version. If you don't know how to do it, I can make an answer.

Comment: I have  created a two substrings and converted second substring into a integer and incremented by 1 it is giving wrong output in case of CD009 output was CD0010 while the expected should be  CD010

Comment: Last digit of what? Digit or number? If digit what to do with 9? 0? Can you add concrete and full expected result from the samples in the question, please? As well as more samples and rules.

Comment: @PrashantVerma there's a different between incrementing a digit and as well as changing other parts of a string. Your input vs expected isn't understandable. It's been asked already to show code, expected output, if you can't how can we help you?

Comment: Thanks for reply Che there is no pattern. It can be mixed string or numeric.For numeric I have done but in mixed case I am struck

Comment: I have a basic idea to solve the problem but not able to implement it properly.Like if I have string CBC004DS009 I need to split this into two parts CBC004DS AND 009. For the second part I have to convert in to integer and increment by 1 so the number would come 010.After that combine both the substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that you can work with. You might want to make it more robust, but I went ahead and added applicable comments to describe what is being done.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var s = "CBC004DS009";

    // get the very last index of the character that is not a number
    var lastNonNumeric = s.LastOrDefault(c => !char.IsDigit(c)); 
    if (lastNonNumeric != '\x0000')
    {
        var numericStart = s.LastIndexOf(lastNonNumeric);

        // grab the number chunk from the string based on the last character found
        var numericValueString = s.Substring(numericStart + 1, s.Length - numericStart - 1);

        // convert that number so we can increment accordingly
        if (int.TryParse(numericValueString, out var newValue))
        {
            newValue += 1;

            // create the new string without the number chunk at the end
            var newString = s.Substring(0, s.Length - numericValueString.Length);

            // append the newly increment number to the end of the string, and pad
            // accordingly based on the original number scheme
            newString += newValue.ToString().PadLeft(numericValueString.Length, '0');

            Console.WriteLine(newString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks d.moncada it worked for me

Comment: @PrashantVerma thanks, if you can, please accept the answer.